# Insert a word at beginning of line

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep

```
this is message1;num:10;
this is message2;num:20;
```

I want to search the value between `num:` and `;`, i.e. `10`, `20`, and insert it at the beginning of the line.

output should be:

```
10 this is message1
20 this is message2
```

How to do this using shell script?

Comment: How to write the script?

Comment: @TaherKhorshidi And another low quality question with no attempt :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ awk -F'[;:]' '{print $3, $1}' file
10 this is message1
20 this is message2
```

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer please.

Comment: No, it is basic awk. Ask a question if after reading the manual some part of it is unclear.

Comment: Cool! I didn't know you could do `-F'[;:]'`! Thanks! I should also go and read the manual :)

Comment: @tommy.carstensen FYI you can use any regexp as the `FS` in any awk. In GNU awk you can additionally use any regexp as the `RS` while in all other awks the RS can only be a single character.

Answer (score 1):

Using sed:

```
sed -e 's/\(.*\);num:\([^;]\+\);/\2 \1/'
```

If your sed implementation supports extended regular expressions, you can make it more readable:

```
sed -re 's/(.*);num:([^;]+);/\2 \1/'
```

The first pair of parentheses remembers the message, the second pair the number. The line is then replaced by the two remembered strings in reverse order.